# How to define the color of regular observations in "sparkline" package in R?

Tags: r, sparklines

I'am using the Sparkline package in a dataset with three observations for years 2000, 2019 and 2020. I have defined colors for max and min values, but I can't find a way to make a dot appear in the remaining observation(s) and give it the color I want.

The following code does not show a dot for 2019:

```
y <- 1:3
x <- c(2000, 2019, 2020)
sparkline::sparkline(y, xvalues = x, maxSpotColor = "red", minSpotColor = "green")
```

[jQuery documentation](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#common) says:

> valueSpots    Specifies which points to draw spots on, and with which
> colour. Accepts a range. For example, to render green spots on all
> values less than 50 and red on values higher use {':49': 'green,
> '50:': 'red'} - New in 2.0

I think I might need to use valueSpots to "draw a black dot on every point but max and min", but I can't find a way to pass such a statement into valueSpots in R. Adding valueSpots = "black" does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
y <- 1:3
x <- c(2000, 2019, 2020)
sparkline::sparkline(y, xvalues = x, maxSpotColor = "red", minSpotColor = "green", valueSpots = list("2" = "black"))
```

[image]

In general, there is the need to specify the mapping for `y` to the desired colors. To generalize, we can calculate `valueSpots` as:

```
pts_in_between = setdiff(unique(y), c(max(y), min(y)))
valueSpots = setNames(as.list(rep("black", length(pts_in_between))), pts_in_between)
```

and then feed into the sparkline, e.g.

```
y<-c(100, 300, 400, 300, 200, 500)
x = c(10, 30, 70, 110, 200, 300)
pts_in_between = setdiff(unique(y), c(max(y), min(y)))
valueSpots = setNames(as.list(rep("black", length(pts_in_between))), pts_in_between)
sparkline::sparkline(values = y, xvalues = x, maxSpotColor = "red", minSpotColor = "green", valueSpots = valueSpots, spotColor = "black")
```

[image]

Note that I also had to set `spotColor = "black"` in the function call to ensure that the last point (if not the max or min) is set to "black" instead of "orange".

Comment: Nice! However, maxSpotColor and minSpotColor set colors for max and min y values. Your answer works well for max and min x values, but if y max were in the second position, i.e 'x<-c(1,3,2)' the code does not work anymore. Would it be possible to make it work for y values?

Comment: One way to do this is by pre-sorting the data, e.g. `x_order = order(x) ; x = x[x_order]; y = y[x_order]`. Then you feed this sorted data into the above. One alternative is to just replace valueSpots with `valueSpots = setNames(as.list(rep("black", list_length)), setdiff(seq_len(length(x)), c(which.max(x), which.min(x))))`

Comment: My bad. I made a mistake in my previous comment.  I meant to ask you about the  case when y = c(1,3,2).  Since your answer solves what I asked, I've accepted it, but will appreciate if you can refer to this case too.

Comment: @GonzaloTF, please see my comment above; does that resolve it for you?

Comment: No, it does not because I made a mistake asking about the case when x=c(1,3,2), but I meant to ask when y =c(1, 3, 2), which is not solved by your previous comment.

Comment: @GonzaloTF, in testing out your ask, I realized my initial explanation wasn't fully correct so I corrected it in my answer and also included the generalized solution.